# Finding a number

Tags: elementary-number-theory

[image]

Every digit has to contain $0-9$. Some possible combinations are:

$98765432$

$87654321$

I am trying by trial and error but I want to know how to solve this by strategy. Any guides?

Also what would strictly decreasing mean?

Comment: 87654321 is not possible because your number have to be even.

Comment: That it "strictly decreases" means that the digits come in strictly descending order, such as in $97654320$ or $76543210$.

Comment: @HowDoIMath Yes you're right, it was a first information from the fact that your number is divisible by $180$ and not a given information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The searched number is composed of the 8 digits decreasing and is divisible by 10, so his last digit is $0$.

He is also divisible by 20, so his dozen digit is neither 1 nor 3, so it is $2$

We just need to remove another digit, and we know the final number is also divisible by 9,

$0+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9=44=36+8$, so the searched number is $97654320$

Answer (score 2):

It has to end with a 0, because it's divisible by 10.

Its digits have to sum up to a multiple of 9 because it's divisible by 9.

It's divisible by 4 so its last two digits can't be "10" or "30".

Therefore they must be "20". (Can't be "40" because there are only two digits missing).

Therefore, the sum of first 6 digits must be of form $3k+1$.

Sum of numbers from $3$ to $9$ is $42=14\cdot 3$.

So we must be missing a $2, 5$ or $8$.

Now you only have 3 numbers left to check. That's easy enough to consider the problem solved.